# How can I test all archives files in a folder to verify if they are corrupted or not?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, archive, archive-utility

I have a folder that contains many files, including some `.zip`, `.tar`, `.tgz`, `7z`, and `gz` files. How can I test all archive files in this folder to verify if they are corrupted or not?

The folder contains subfolders, which also contain archive files that I want to check. I use Mac OS X 10.10.

On Microsoft Windows I use some file manager to list all archives:

[image]

then use 7zip to test all archives at once:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to run 7z from terminal to accomplish this. In the terminal, you can use command such as

```
7z t -r *.tar
```

If you are certain that the folder contains only archives that can 7zip handle, then it will work

```
7z t -r *
```

Comment: `7z` is not part of a standard macOS installation as far as I know.

Comment: It is not, but can be downloaded for free. Also, there is 7z archive in question, therefore I kind of expected the user to have this tool installed already.

Comment: It might benefit future visitors to see how the tool can installed.